# Can't add field to argument object

Tags: javascript

Trying to modify mongoose.findOne result object. I just add jwt token string to finded user object.
Then I have some mistery: I see, that object contains new property, bit it is not!

**function code:**

```
function login(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne().byEmailPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password).exec(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({error: err});
        }
        result.token = jwt.sign(
            {
                id: result._id,
                exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60)
            },
            process.env.JWT_SECRET
        );
        console.log('result Type: ', typeof result);
        console.log('result.token: ', result.token);
        console.log('result object: ', result);
        res.json(result);
        next();
    })
}
```

**console.log:**

```
result Type:  object
result.token:  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlYTc0ZTMyYmZiM2ViMDdjMGUzNzA1ZSIsImV4cCI6MTU4ODA5NzI0MSwiaWF0IjoxNTg4MDkzNjQxfQ.iHCGt5
LXelafHYySftER3plvDivcPKRouxYFsAbmHvo
result object:  { _id: 5ea74e32bfb3eb07c0e3705e,
  email: 'test@mail.russs',
  fullname: 'Ivanov Ivan' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned the `User` that you got from mongodb to any variable, and then you need to set the `token` property of that variable, then `.save()` that `User` that you saved into the variable